# how to show image picker in bottom sheet flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to use image picker like insta or facebook when I click on a button it should popsup the bottom sheet with my gallery images and scaffold should also resize to show options just like in a design provider. Thanks

[image]